# Multiple IP addresses for Resource Record Sets of Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I'm studying aws route53, when I'm creating the resource record set, I can add multiple IP addresses to value of record set.

[image]

What is the purpose of multiple IP addresses here? 
Ex: my domain will route to server 1 and server 2. I tried to stop server 1 and access to my domain, but it did NOT route to server 2.

What is the issue here?
Could you please explain multiple IP addresses of record set's value?
Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The correct question is stated in the AWS Route 53 documentation:

https://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/#associate_multiple_ip_with_single_record

> Q. Can I associate multiple IP addresses with a single record?
>
> Yes. Associating multiple IP addresses with a single record is often
>   used for balancing the load of geographically-distributed web servers.
>   Amazon Route 53 allows you to list multiple IP addresses for an A
>   record and responds to DNS requests with the list of all configured IP
>   addresses.

This method is usually used by Highly Available applications that will parse the results and decide what to do with the results, such as randomly or programmatically return one result only or list all the resources available in a cluster.

The response will vary according to the the specified "Routing Policy", if you specify "Simple" (default) one you all get all the entries for that record in the response.

Comment: Firebase gives me 2 IP addresses.   Route53 console does not allow adding 2 A records with the same name.   To add multiple IPs to an A record, just add 2 IPs , each on a separate line in the A-record definition.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it randomly resolves the name to one of the IP addresses (I believe it is done turn by turn, so one of your IPs then the other is used), but you have no control over which one.