# Under what circumstances does checkip.amazonaws.com return multiple addresses?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to understand an issue [reported by a user against one of my open source projects](https://github.com/nchammas/flintrock/issues/271). When they query `checkip.amazonaws.com` they sometimes get back multiple, comma-delimited IP addresses.

I couldn't find any information about this, so I'm curious:

1. Is there any proper documentation for this Amazon service?
2. Under what circumstances does `checkip.amazonaws.com` return multiple addresses?
3. When it *does* return multiple addresses, what do they mean? Is there a significance to the order?

Comment: The checkip.amazonaws.com endpoint isn't documented or officially supported by AWS afaik. No-one should rely on it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the rightmost value as authoritative, and any other values as informational but untrusted, because they are actually being copied from the headers of the incoming request.

Testing reveals that this endpoint uses HTTP `X-Forwarded-For` semantics and returns the final resulting value... so if the user is behind any kind of proxy that injects `X-Forwarded-For`, those values *from the incoming request* are included in the response and the actual address that was used to contact this service appears on the right, as the last value.

You can prove this for yourself by injecting one or more `X-Forwarded-For` headers into the request.

The values to the left, if present, are likely to be private, internal IP addresses on the requester's network, but the design of `X-Forwarded-For` means they can neither be proven nor disproven as accurate.  The one on the far right is always the one that is correct.

Note that seeing this behavior at all is much less likely if you use https to access the endpoint, since proxies are far less likely to be able to inject such headers. (Not impossible with an MITM proxy and certificate forgery, but a well-behaving system would never do that.)

This service from AWS is a troubleshooting feature that does not appear to be officially documented.  The fact that it uses `X-Forwarded-For` suggests that this test site -- not surprisingly -- is hosted behind a load balancer, and the appearance of multiple addresses in the response was probably an unintended "feature" that arises as a consequence of how it was originally implemented.

Best practice is probably to create your own "what is my IP" service for embedding in your own products, because sometimes public services are abused by malware/botnet authors.  When this happens, your software can be incorrectly assumed to be malware, which makes a mess for you to try to explain over the panic that can ensue.  Third party services, even if "public," may prefer not to have their services called without permission.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the `checkip.amazonaws.com` service doesn't return multiple IPs anymore:

```
$ curl --header "X-Forwarded-For: 10.10.10.3" \
  --header "X-Forwarded-For: 10.10.10.2" \
  --header "X-Forwarded-For: 10.10.10.1" \
  http://checkip.amazonaws.com/
10.10.10.3
```

Anyone still have a case where multiple IPs are returned?

Answer (score 0):

The service `checkip.amazonaws.com` provides the public IP address of the client making the request. I can think of two reasons that more than one IP address can be returned. However, I do not have access to the code that AWS wrote to know exactly what they are processing. I have written a PHP service that does the same thing.

- The client's Internet router is multi-homed. This means that the router is connected to more than one Internet for either redundancy, performance or load balancing.
- Proxy servers, load balancers, etc. can append their IP addresses to the HTTP headers which can result in a smart service displaying more than one IP address if it does not know which is which (client IP or proxy IP).

I am sure that there are more cases. However, you should be parsing the IP address string and splitting or terminating the string on a comma, tab, etc. so that you are only specifying the first `valid` IP address.

Answer (score -4):

A DNS Name can be associated with multiple IP addresses.

From [AWS | Amazon Route 53 | FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/):

> **Q. Can I associate multiple IP addresses with a single record?**
>
> Yes. Associating multiple IP addresses with a single record is often used for balancing the load of geographically-distributed web servers. Amazon Route 53 allows you to list multiple IP addresses for an A record and responds to DNS requests with the list of all configured IP addresses.

See also: [StackOverflow: Multiple IP addresses for Resource Record Sets of Route 53](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40841273/174777)

Comment: This has nothing to do with DNS records. Request is always coming from one IP only, it can not come from multiple and it is definitely not related to DNS records.